# how to get input value of a json data when submitted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have json data file. I want to make a search with the names of the data and display the typed names when I click the search button.

I get the value of input in the console when I type something however I am not able to display it on the screen
How can I display the value of this input ?

my code is below

```
PostResults.jsx

import React from "react";


const PostResults = (props) => {
  const {name} = props.posts
  return(
        <div className="">
          <p className="titles">{name}</p>
        </div>
  )
}

export default PostResults
```

```
Posts.jsx

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PostResults from './PostResults'



const Posts = (props) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm,setSearchTerm]=useState([]);

    const getData = () => {
    fetch('data.json')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
      //console.log(response)
    })
    .then(data => {
      setPosts(data)
      console.log(data)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  },[])

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
      {searchTerm ? searchTerm : console.log("none")}
    }
     
  return(
       <div className="">
                <input 
                  type="text" 
                  placeholder="Search Anything" 
                  name="query" 
                  onChange={e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                  className="search-input" 
                />
                <button 
                  onClick={submitHandler} 
                  type="submit" 
                  className="search-button"
                >
                  <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
              </button>
               {posts.map(posts => (
                <PostResults key={posts.id} posts={posts}/>
              ))}
       </div>
  )
}

export default Posts
```

```
App.jsx

import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Posts from './components/Posts'


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
      < Posts />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of `data.json`?

Comment: it is in my public folder as data.json. and the structure is below. there are 111 objects in it with different names.         
{
    "id": "6021385560f240c61bf30edf",
    "guid": "7049f25c-87f6-4092-b1c0-767c57e7c249",
    "name": "Hines Daniel",
    "title": "LUMBREX",
    "email": "hinesdaniel@lumbrex.com",
    "phone": "+1 (916) 421-3534",
    "address": "686 Cropsey Avenue, Yonah, North Dakota, 4502",
    "createdAt": "2019-01-04T10:17:52 -03:00"
  },

Comment: .then(data => {
      setPosts([data])
    })

Comment: I actually did this. .then(data => {setPosts(data)}.  It renders all the data. but what I need is I want to display names that I type in input bar when I click search button. I am getting the value of input in the below code . it displays on the console. but when I remove console.log, it doesnt display it on the screen                                                                                                                                 
"const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
      {searchTerm ? console.log(searchTerm) : console.log("none")}
    }"